# How to model user profiles with languages spoken? How to store the languages?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

Say User1 speaks English,Chinese and User2 speaks English,Spanish.

Assume that there will be many more languages to choose from.

Should I be storing this like:

```
user
---
id: 1 | languages_spoken: [1,2]
id: 2 | languages_spoken: [1,3]
```

or

```
user
---
id: 1 | languages_spoken: ["English","Chinese"]
id: 2 | languages_spoken: ["English","Spanish"]
```

If I went with `languages_spoken: int[]`, how should I convert these to the displayed values? Should I have a separate table `language` which maps `1->"English"` or should I just convert this with code on the frontend?

(I am coming from a NoSQL background so this is confusing to me.)

Answer (score 0):

Better have 3 separated tables.

```
User: user_id (pk), user_name
Languages: language_id (pk), language
User_Languages: user_id (fk), language_id (fk)
```